# Generating random numbers in bash $RANDOM always returning zero

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to generate a random number in Bash, but it looks like $RANDOM is always returning zero.

I am using the following code

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash

testing=$((RANDOM))
echo $testing
VAR=$((RANDOM%200+100))
echo $VAR
```

Result :

```
0
100
```

Anybody any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `#!/bin/sh` line from your script. `$RANDOM` works in `bash`, not in `sh`.

Comment: Thank you...   Thats the reason why i dont like to import foreign code...   there is allways a catch... used the first two lines due to the script im currently editing